# SQL request on datetime

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a SQL request (from PHP) to extract data depending on a date.
My database is: id(int), name(text), date(datetime)

I have searched different ways on the web and on stackoverflow and tested the following :

```
SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE date BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE DATEDIFF( date, $date2 )
```

but none of them works

my complete code is:

```
    require 'connect.php'; // this connection works I can add element to the database
    $date1 = new DateTime('2018/01/01 10:00:00');
    $date2 = new DateTime('2019/01/01 10:00:00');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE date BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2";  
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE DATEDIFF(date, $date2 )";

    $req = $pdo->query($sql);  

    while($data = $req->fetch()) 
    {
        echo $data['id'];
        echo" ";
    }
```

But it doesn't work: nothing is returned (of course in my database I have dates between date1 and date2).

Do you know what is wrong ?

Comment: While the specific error is a lack of inverted commas, more generally, writing queries this way leaves you wide open to sql injection. See about parametrized queries

Comment: SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE date BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2 does not this statement return any result direct from db?

Comment: you state you are storing it as "bookingDate" but you are querying off of "date"  If it's the former, then your query need to compare bookingDate

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin : nothing is returned

Comment: @nomistic : sorry bookingDate is no the real name, it is date - I correct the question

Comment: are you getting any results when you run the query directly in your database?  In other words `SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE date BETWEEN '2018/01/01 10:00:00' AND '2019/01/01 10:00:00'`  and if so, if it's working there, try the same thing in your on-page query feeding it actual values.

Comment: @Freddlow http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfce1c/1 check this link and see no difference between your and think link query ,now if this query worked well then why not yours

Answer (score 0):

You could specify that the date should be greater than date1 and less than date2:

```
SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE date >= $date1 AND date <= $date2
```

also, as Strawberry correctly stated, use this code to insert parameters securely:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE date >= :start AND date <= :end";
```

so, your code should be:

```
try{
    $req= $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $req->execute(array(
        'start'=>$date1->format('Y-m-d'), 
        'end'=>$date2->format('Y-m-d')
    ));
    $id_contratto = $db->lastInsertId();
}catch(PDOException $ex){
    //handle errors here
}

while($data = $req->fetch()) 
{
    echo $data['id'];
    echo" ";
}
```

Comment: it gives the same result

Comment: how is date defined in your database? shouldn't it be "bookingDate"?

Comment: also, you should format the date in MySql format:

$date1->format('Y-m-d'), just edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: Same format as date1 et date2. I filled the table with request like $sql = "INSERT INTO myBase VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 5, '2018/08/26 09:20:00', '2018/08/27 10:10:00')";

Comment: this is not a correct date format, you should insert it as: 2018-08-26

Comment: and if you have this [id(int), name(text), bookingDate(datetime)], why your insert statement contains two dates?

Comment: sorry I have other dates in my database but I don't use them yet

Comment: have you tried to correct the date format as 2018-08-26?

Answer (score 0):

seems like the queries are wrong

```
SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE bookingDate BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2";
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE DATEDIFF( BookingDate, $date2 ) > 0
```

Comment: same result, nothing returned

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your query, but with $date1 and $date2. 
The $date1 and $date2 just be kept as a string format. 
    $date1 = '2018-01-01 10:00:00';
    $date2 ='2019-01-01 10:00:00';

Comment: It makes an error. In my table dates are in dateime format

Comment: Yep, in DB, the date should be saved as datetime. What is the type of SQL are you using? SQL server, Mysql, or ...? What is the error of it produced? what does final query string look like

Comment: I use MySQL (with PHPMyAdmin). When I way there is an error, it is just that my PHP page that does the request can not display

Comment: How about  update your  date format with dash separator. Like SELECT * FROM myBase WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 10:00:00' AND '2019-01-01 10:00:00'